# $n$-fold degeneracy, ground state, toric code

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer, topological-order, quantum-error-correction

I'm having a hard time understanding the degeneracy of the Kitaev toric code. Can anyone explain to me with details the following:

- How do we find the ground states of the toric code and its gape?
- What does 4-fold degeneracy means?

Comment: Have you read Kitaev's paper (the first 8 or so pages)? https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9707021 I feel like it really is just the best place to look, you can't really condense it any further and still have it be of any use I think

Comment: Especially the second question gives me the idea that your issue is not with the toric code, but with quantum systems in general. Maybe it would be better if you read a more general introduction first?

Comment: @Mr. Joshua, yes I have read them but they are not detailed enough (at least for me). For example, on page 5 he says the ground state coincides with the protected subspace TOR(k), how do we show that?

Comment: and I couldn't understand the method, using string operators, to prove that the toric code is of dim=4

Answer (score 7):

We can calculate degeneracy of the ground space of the Toric code in a few different ways.

### Using stabilizer formalism

A simple way to find the degeneracy uses the [stabilizer formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabilizer_code). The relevant result says that a stabilizer group generated by $g$ independent generators fixes states in a $2^{n-g}$-dimensional subspace of the $n$-qubit Hilbert space. See Proposition 10.5 on page 458 in Nielsen & Chuang's "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information".

The stabilizer group of the Toric code on $2k^2$ qubits is generated by $k^2$ site operators $A_s$ and $k^2$ plaquette operators $B_p$ defined as

$$
A_s = \prod_{j \in s} \sigma^x_j \,\,\,\,\,\,
B_p = \prod_{j \in p} \sigma^z_j \tag1
$$

(c.f. equation $(1)$ in [Kitaev's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9707021)).
However, since $(\sigma^z_j)^2 = (\sigma^z_j)^2 = I$ we see that any one of the  site operators is equal to the product of all the others and similarly for the plaquette operators. Therefore, we have $2k^2-2$ independent generators. By the result cited above, the stabilizer group of the Toric code fixes states in a subspace which has $2^{2k^2 - (2k^2-2)} = 4$ dimensions, i.e. is $4$-fold degenerate.

### Using homology

An intuitive way of calculating the dimension of the ground space of the Toric code uses the concept of [homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics)).

The Hamiltonian of the Toric code is defined as

$$
H = -\sum_s A_s - \sum_p B_p
$$

where $s$ ranges over sites and $p$ ranges over plaquettes of the lattice (c.f. equation $(4)$ in [Kitaev's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9707021)). The operators $A_s$ and $B_p$ commute for all $s$ and $p$, so there is a basis that consists of their shared eigenvectors and $H$ is diagonal in this basis. The eigenvalues of $A_s$ and $B_p$ are $+1$ and $-1$, so we see that the lowest eigenvalue of $H$ corresponds to the eigenvectors $|\xi_i\rangle$ of $A_s$ and $B_p$ associated with eigenvalue $+1$. In other words, the ground space of $H$ is

$$
\mathcal{L} = \{|\xi_i\rangle\,:\,A_s|\xi_i\rangle = |\xi_i\rangle, B_p|\xi_i\rangle = |\xi_i\rangle\,\text{for all}\,p,s\}
$$

(c.f. equation $(2)$ in the paper).

Note that this analysis also reveals the gap between closest eigenvalues of $H$. The gap is due to the sign change in the eigenvalue of a site or plaquette operator. However, since sites can only change sign in pairs and plaquettes can only change sign in pairs, we see that the gap is equal to $4$.

Now, for a set $a$ of links of the lattice define

$$
A_a = \prod_{j \in a} \sigma^x_j
$$

and similarly for a set $b$ of links of the dual lattice define

$$
B_b = \prod_{j \in b} \sigma^z_j.
$$

If $a$ is a closed loop, then $A_a$ commutes with all site and plaquette operators $(1)$. However, only the closed loops which are boundaries of two-dimensional regions can be generated as products of site and plaquette operators. This allows us to define operators which preserve $\mathcal{L}$ while acting non-trivially on it.

The first homology group of the torus has rank $2$ reflecting the fact that there are two types of loops that are not boundaries. Denote the two homologically non-trivial loops of the lattice $\alpha$ (running vertically) and $\beta$ (running horizontally) and similarly for the dual lattice $\alpha'$ (running vertically) and $\beta'$ (running horizontally).

The key observation is that $\alpha$ and $\beta'$ have an odd number of qubits in common. Therefore, the operators $A_\alpha$ and $B_{\beta'}$ anticommute, as do $A_\beta$ and $B_{\alpha'}$. This is impossible in a one-dimensional space, so we immediately conclude that the ground space of $H$ is degenerate. In each pair of anticommuting operators one operator switches the $+1$ and $-1$ eigenvectors of the other, so we see that the degeneracy is at least $4$-fold.

See also [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0110143) for an accessible explanation.

### Using elementary linear algebra

A more elementary way to calculate the dimension of the ground space of $H$ is based on counting solutions to the system of linear equations that determines the computational basis representation of the ground states.

We will construct an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{L}$ by constructing orthonormal simultaneous eigenstates of the site and plaquette operators.
Let $|b\rangle=|b_0b_1\dots b_{2k^2-1}\rangle$ with $b\in\{0, 1\}^{2k^2}$ and $b_i\in\{0, 1\}$ denote a computational basis state. The state $|b\rangle$ is a $+1$ eigenstate of all plaquette operators $B_p$ if and only if

$$
b_{N,p} + b_{E,p} + b_{S,p} + b_{W,p} = 0 \pmod 2\tag2
$$

where $b_{N,p}, b_{E,p}, b_{S,p}$ and $b_{W,p}$ denote the state of the four qubits around the plaquette $p$. There are $k^2-1$ independent constraints of this form and $2k^2$ variables, so the solution space of the system of linear equations $(2)$ is a $(k^2+1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{Z}^{2k^2}$. None of the computational basis states $|b\rangle$ is an eigenvector of a site operator. However, note that if $|b\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $B_p$ associated with eigenvalue $+1$ then so is $A_s|b\rangle$ for any site $s$. Therefore, we can combine the states $|b\rangle$ obtained by solving the linear system $(2)$ into superposition states to obtain common $+1$ eigenvectors $|\xi_i\rangle$ of all site and plaquette operators.

For a computational basis state $|b\rangle$ of the lattice, define

$$
v_1(|b\rangle) = \sum_{i\in v} b_i \pmod 2 \\
v_2(|b\rangle) = \sum_{i\in h} b_i \pmod 2
$$

for a vertical loop $v$ around the torus and a horizontal loop $h$. Note that since $|b\rangle$ is a $+1$ eigenstate of all plaquette operators the definition of $v_1$ and $v_2$ does not depend on the choice of $v$ and $h$. In Kitaev's paper, the values of the two sums are called "topological numbers".

Note that for any site operator $A_s$, we have $v_1(|b\rangle) = v_1(A_s|b\rangle)$. Therefore, we partition the space of solutions to $(2)$ into four subspaces $C_i$ according to Kitaev's  topological numbers $v_1$ and $v_2$. Thus, each $C_i$ is $(k^2-1)$-dimensional. Consequently

$$
|\xi_i\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{k^2-1}}} \sum_{b \in C_i} |b\rangle
$$

(c.f. equation $(3)$ in Kitaev's paper).

Note that there are $2^{k^2+1}$ solutions to $(2)$ and each $|\xi_i\rangle$ uses $2^{k^2-1}$. Therefore, there are $2^{k^2+1}/2^{k^2-1} = 4$ states $|\xi_i\rangle$. In fact we can index the states $|\xi_i\rangle$ by $i=(v_1, v_2)$ where $v_1\in\{0, 1\}$ and $v_2\in\{0, 1\}$ are Kitaev's topological numbers. Since these states form an orthonormal basis of the ground space $\mathcal{L}$ of the Toric code we see that the space is four-dimensional.